# How do I center a pair of Views inside a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How do I center a pair of `Views` within a `ConstraintLayout` as below, **without nesting**? They need to be touching, and centered as a single unit.

[image]

I tried anchoring them to each other and their parent but then they're not touching each other so I added a horizontal bias for both but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance...

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="14dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"        
    android:src="@drawable/checkmark"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/textView"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/some_text"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: A [packed chain](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#Chains) should do it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes it did. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set a chainstyle attribute for the head of the chain which is the first `View` on the left in a horizontal chain. The style that will give the expected result is `packed`. A bias will not be needed in this case.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="14dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/checkmark"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/textView"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/some_text"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```